# What is the difference between sse2neon and arm_neon.h?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sse, arm64, neon

I am trying to build software to run on `aws graviton3`. To get the most out of the performance, aws advice to use [sse2neon](https://github.com/DLTcollab/sse2neon) to port codes with SSE intrinsics to neon [(porting-codes-with-sseavx-intrinsics-to-neon)](https://github.com/aws/aws-graviton-getting-started/blob/main/c-c%2B%2B.md#porting-codes-with-sseavx-intrinsics-to-neon)

While modifying the headers I found that `arm_neon.h` is included when arm64 architecture is detected. Is there any benefits of using `sse2neon` instead of `arm_neon.h`? Should include both headers side by side?

And what is the difference between them anyway?

Comment: *Is there any befinifts of using sse2neon instead of arm_neon.h?* - The benefit is that you can compile code written to use use x86 SSE intrinsics like `_mm_add_epi32` on `__m128i` vectors, instead of having to manually port to use `uint32x4_t` with `vaddq_u32` (intrinsics guide: https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiesreturnbasetype=[int,uint]&f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=[Neon]&f:@navigationhierarchiesarchitectures=[v7]&f:@navigationhierarchiesinstructiongroup=[Vector%20arithmetic,Add,Addition])

Comment: Does this mean I can use both `-msse2 -mfpmath=sse` flags on arm64?

Comment: No, you're still compiling for ARM64, you're just including a header that defines those type and function names using NEON intrinsics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any befinifts of using `sse2neon` instead of `arm_neon.h`?

The benefit is that you can compile code written to use use x86 SSE intrinsics like `_mm_add_epi32` on `__m128i` vectors ([Intel intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&text=padd)), instead of having to manually port to use `uint32x4_t` with `vaddq_u32` ([ARM intrinsics guide](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiesreturnbasetype=%5Bint,uint%5D&f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=%5BNeon%5D&f:@navigationhierarchiesarchitectures=%5BA64%5D&f:@navigationhierarchiesinstructiongroup=%5BVector%20arithmetic,Add,Addition%5D) filtered for integer addition on AArch64 with NEON)

NEON and SSE2 are different instruction sets with some different instructions, e.g. different shuffles.  And NEON having a lot of horizontal pairwise stuff like addition.  But x86 having `_mm_movemask_epi8` to take one bit per byte of the vector and put it in an `int`; x86 CPUs can fairly efficiently get data between SIMD and integer domains, useful for stuff like `memcmp` or `strlen` when you want to branch on SIMD compare results.  ARM / AArch64 CPUs don't have an equivalent instruction.

Of course for simple stuff like simple vertical operations, there are 1:1 drop in replacements, so no benefit to porting by hand.  But for stuff where the `sse2neon` implementation of an x86 intrinsic takes multiple ARM intrinsics, it can be worth porting manually, especially if that's inside a loop, not just cleanup that runs once.

Comment: Thanks now I understand better what the library means by translation. 
However, the code I am trying to modify has `#if defined(__SSE2__)` whenever sse2 instructions are used. With ssee2neon I can extend this condition to #if defined(__SSE2__) || defined(__ARM_NEON__). Am I correct?

Comment: @RamiZK: No, that wouldn't make sense for code that uses SSE2 intrinsics.  `sse2neon` should define `__SSE2__`.  If it doesn't, `#define __SSE2__ 1` yourself along with your #include of it.